# WPF Listview: Force validation when adding or removing data bound collection

Tags: wpf, validation, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm trying to build a validation rule for a ListView which should be valid only when there is at least one item on its data bound collection. I've ended up creating a new ValidationRule derived class which looks like this:

```
public class NoEmptyCollectionValidationRule : ValidationRule {
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo) {
        var items = (IEnumerable<Object>) value;
        var valid = items != null && items.Any();
        return new ValidationResult(valid, "oops");
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm using it on my ListView:

```
<ListView Name="_lContatos" Height="95"  
        SelectionMode="Single" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedContact}">
<ListView.ItemsSource>
    <Binding Path="Contacts" Mode="TwoWay" 
                UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
        <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <utils:NoEmptyCollectionValidationRule
                ErrorMessage="Lista de contactos não pode estar vazia."  
                ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
</ListView.ItemsSource>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Contato" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Extensão" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Extension}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Tipo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ContactKind}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Unfortunately, this will only work when the collection is replaced by a new one. Besides this scenario, I also need to cover another one: I need to evaluate my validation rule when someone adds or removes items from the ListView's data bound collection. I've thought about intercepting the CollectionChanged event (it's an ObservableCollection). In theory, I should be able to force the evaluation of my rule by calling the ValidateWithoutUpdate method:

```
_viewModel.Contacts.CollectionChanged +=
    (sender, e) => _lContatos
        .GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty)
        .ValidateWithoutUpdate();
```

Unfortunately, and even though the CollectionChanged event is being fired correctly whenever I add or remove a contact from the data bound collection, my custom validation rule is only called once (the first time the event is fired). For instance, suppose I start with an empty contact collection. Adding an item through my form ends up firing the CollectionChanged event and my custom validation rule does end up being called and the initial validation error is cleared up. However, removing this new contact and/or adding new ones to the collection will still fire the CollectionChanged event, but my custom validation rule is no longer being called.

Any clues on how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I think it's due to the fact that WPF binding validation is based on scalar valued properties rather than collection based properties.

Maybe have a look at this sort of solution: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/codefx/2012/05/16/sample-of-may-16th-wpf-listbox-validation/